# ShellAndWait not working

Tags: vba

I'm using ShellAndWait from here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx and I keep getting 1 returned (which means the command didn't work in Windows). But when i paste my cmdLine into Start, Run box it runs fine. Any ideas? I'm using Excel VBA for this and here's my code that I'm calling ShellAndWait with
What am I doing wrong?

thank you very much

```
Sub test()

Dim cmdLine As String

cmdLine = "C:\Documents and Settings\natalie.rynda\My Documents\Marta\Calling Files\_SFTP\Minacs.bat"

ShellAndWait cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser

If ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 0 Then
MsgBox "yes!!!!!!"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 1 Then
MsgBox "1"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 2 Then
MsgBox "2"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 3 Then
MsgBox "3"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 4 Then
MsgBox "4"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 5 Then
MsgBox "5"
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 1000, vbHide, PromptUser) = 6 Then
MsgBox "6"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to see what's going on in the command window opened by ShellAndWait --- substitute vbNormalFocus for vbHide.  After you find and fix the problem, you can switch back to vbHide.

Comment: it flashes too quick, i can't catch what it says. also, if it's giving an error then why is ShellAndWait saying it was a success? and thank you

Comment: i can't catch the message but it's something about some command not being recognized. I'm lost, if i run the Minacs.bat by doubleclicking it everything works fine. Also, why is it giving me Success from ShellAndWait?

Comment: ShellAndWait does not care if your batch file executed correctly, only that it executed within the time-frame you set. Success does not mean that the batch file was successful, but that ShellAndWait did not fail, and did not time-out. I believe that the error is in your batch file, not ShellAndWait, and that you should use HansUp's code to execute ShellAndWait for the reasons they mention in their answer.

Comment: i'm trying it now, but if the error was in the batch file then why is it working by double-clicking. also, ShellAndWait that i'm using does care if it was executed correctly as far as i can understand. Otherwise i don't see the need for 6 outcomes. I can be wrong on this though.

Comment: If you check the return values for ShellAndWait you can see that 0 for success is only if "the Shell'd process terminated successfully before the TimeOutMs interval expired" The process you Shell'd doesn't need to work properly, just terminate successfully. It looks like you and HansUp solved the problem of it working when double-clicking and not when run through the shell command. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter **PAUSE** as the last line in Minacs.bat to keep the command window open until you press a key.  That should give you a chance to see what's happening.

You should also revise your VBA code.  It calls the same ShellAndWait command at least twice ... once before the `If` block, and then again to start the If block.  And it can keep trying until it hits an `If/ElseIf` condition which matches the return value from ShellAndWait.

Change your code to execute ShellAndWait once time only, and store the return value in a variable.  Then you can evaluate the variable in a `Select Case` block.

```
Sub test()
Dim cmdLine As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim lngResult As Long

cmdLine = "C:\TEMP\Minacs.bat"

'lngResult = ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) '
lngResult = ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbNormalFocus, AbandonWait)

Select Case lngResult
Case 0
    'does some stuff here, like send an email, omitted '
Case 1
    strMsg = "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & _
        "Wait operation failed due to a Windows error."
Case 2
    strMsg = "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & _
        "The operation timed out."
Case 3
    strMsg = "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & _
        "An invalid value was passed to the procedure."
Case 4
    strMsg = "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & _
        "The system abandoned the wait."
Case 5, 6
    strMsg = "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & _
        "The user abandoned the wait."
Case Else
    strMsg = "WTF?!!!"
End Select

If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then
    MsgBox strMsg
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, i know i called it twice, i thought maybe i was putting it in the wrong spot, i was so stuck that i was ready to try the stupidest things. tryint the PAUSE now and thank you for the revise, learned a bunch, will use yours

Comment: ))))))))))))))))))))) i love the WTF)))))))))))))))))

Comment: 'psftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 

how is this possible? and why does it work by double clicking? psftp.exe is in the same c:\temp folder

Comment: sorry,  "i know i called it twice, i thought maybe i was putting it in the wrong spot", disregard this. at some point i had that line there twice and i thought i still did when i posted it. i didn't know that using it in the IF statement calls it again, thank you for that as well

Comment: @lalachka If it still complains that it can't find psftp, try giving it the full path including the file extension.  On my system, the PuTTY folder is under Program Files.  Because of the space in that folder name, I would enclose the whole thing in quotes like this: `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\psftp.exe"`

Comment: i'm sorry, give it how? like in the example you gave for SFTP with VBA? i saw it but didn't understand, sorry, can you please explain
EDIT you mean in the batchfile, instead of psftp type "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\psftp.exe"?

Comment: you're amazing, it worked. thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! and thank you for the WTF as Case Else, it was a mood lifter

Comment: Sounds like you got it before I could get back to you.  Congrats.  And glad you enjoyed my Case Else.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add

> batchlog.txt

to allow the result that flashes quickly on the screen to be captured to a file.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, i just thought to try a different folder, C:\temp and it worked, so it's something with my folder, will keep testing to see what exactly

**EDIT**

It's still not working. now it's going through and returns 0 which is Success but the file is not posted to the SFTP site. Here's the exact code i'm using

```
Dim cmdLine As String
```

cmdLine = "C:\TEMP\Minacs.bat"

ShellAndWait cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait

```
If ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 0 Then


'does some stuff here, like send an email, omitted


ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 1 Then
MsgBox "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & "Wait operation failed due to a Windows error."
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 2 Then
MsgBox "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & "The operation timed out."
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 3 Then
MsgBox "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & "An invalid value was passed to the procedure."
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 4 Then
MsgBox "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & "The system abandoned the wait."
ElseIf ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 100000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 5 Or ShellAndWait(cmdLine, 10000, vbHide, AbandonWait) = 6 Then
MsgBox "The file hasn't been uploaded." & vbCrLf & "The user abandoned the wait."
End If
```